# what's the term for who's talking to who?

Tags: grammar, obscure-terms

I was updating a change in my demo app that looks like:

-"Wow that was cool...but how can I work with you for python/django/and beyond?"

+"Wow that was cool...but how can I work with your author for python/django/and beyond?"

Basically, the robot is talking in the README, and in the sentence above, he reads your mind. Being myself and not a robot, and not writing often, I forgot the robot was supposed to be talking. My commit looked like:

[master 2c4f52a] change who's talking to who

which is silly, as I don't remember the term. What's it called for who the writer makes talk to who?

Comment: Added/changed/etc. the robot-talk-to-user feature.

Comment: well, isn't there a literary term for the scope of who's speaking?

Comment: The person who is speaking is "the speaker." The person on the receiving end, listening to the person speaking is "the listener."

Comment: there isn't a term for the general thing though? not naming the parties, but the concept of who's speaking to who? I swear I remember somethin from ENC1001

Comment: What do you mean by "the concept of who's speaking to who?" The concept is called "talking" or "communication."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the word you're trying to remember from your English class is

**person**

"a grammatical category applied esp. to pronouns and verbs, used to distinguish between the speaker of an utterance, the person addressed, and other people or things spoken about. Compare first person, second person, third person."  Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary